# How can I scroll to the top/bottom of web page with a three finger gesture?

Tags: software-recommendation, trackpad, multi-touch, macos

I'd like to use a three finger swipe to scroll to the top or bottom of a web page. Is there a way to make that work?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## [BetterTouchTool](http://blog.boastr.net/) (free)

[image]

Comment: It works pretty well, but the window needs to have focus. And it doesn't work with all windows - I guess it depends on how the receiving applications interprets the event.